# Is there a method to add and an arry of objects to the end of an array of objects without makeing a for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to add an object to the end of another object but the methods im finding add extra keys I dont want. Here is what im looking for:

```
let obj1 = [{"d": "1", "t": "1"}, {"d": "2", "t": "2"}]
let obj2 = [{"d": "3", "t": "3"}, {"d": "4", "t": "4"}]

desired output =
[{"d": "1", "t": "1"}, {"d": "2", "t": "2"}, {"d": "3", "t": "3"}, {"d": "4", "t": "4"}]
```

Alternatively if there is a way to add and object in the middle of another that would be fantastic but i havent found a way to do that yet so spliting then pushing then adding back together is my work arround.

```
let obj1 = [{"d": "1", "t": "1"}, {"d": "2", "t": "2"}, {"d": "4", "t": "4"}]
let obj2 = [{"d": "3", "t": "3"}]

desired output =
[{"d": "1", "t": "1"}, {"d": "2", "t": "2"}, {"d": "3", "t": "3"}, {"d": "4", "t": "4"}]
```

Edit:
Ive previously tride obj1.push(obj2) which returns:

```
[{"d": "1", "t": "1"},{"d": "2", "t": "2"}[{"d": "3", "t": "3"},{"d": "4", "t": "4"}]]
```

And obj3 = {obj1, obj2} which returns:

```
{obj1: [{"d": "1", "t": "1"},{"d": "2", "t": "2"}],obj2: [{"d": "3", "t": "3"},{"d": "4", "t": "4"}]}
```

And obj3 = {...obj1, ...obj2} and idk whats going on here:

```
{
  '0': {"d": "3", "t": "3"},
  '1': {"d": "4", "t": "4"},
  '2': {"d": "2", "t": "2"}
}
```

Comment: what methods? You do need to show an attempt at solving. This looks very straightforward if you've at all searched for how to concatenate arrays or sorting arrays by object values

Comment: You can use `concat` and/or `splice`, but they'll iterate over the input in any case.

Comment: "*Im trying to add an object to the end of another object*" - you're talking of *array* object specifically here, right? Use that term in your searches and you'll get better results. "*the methods im finding add extra keys*" - I really doubt that. What did you find? Can you post the non-working code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax `...`

```js
const obj1 = [{"d": "1", "t": "1"}, {"d": "2", "t": "2"}]
const obj2 = [{"d": "3", "t": "3"}, {"d": "4", "t": "4"}]
const obj3 = [...obj1, ...obj2]

console.log(obj3)
```

Comment: Will not work for unsorted arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) your arrays:

```js
const obj1 = [{"d": "1", "t": "1"}, {"d": "2", "t": "2"}, {"d": "4", "t": "4"}]
const obj2 = [{"d": "3", "t": "3"}]
const obj3 = obj1.concat(obj2).sort((a, b) => a.d - b.d)

console.log(obj3)
```